# The number of ways in which four cards be selected from a pack of 52 cards such that there is exactly one pair ( pair has same number or alphabet)

Tags: combinatorics

Problem :

The number of ways in which four cards be selected from a pack of 52 cards such that there is exactly one pair ( pair has same number or alphabet)

What I tried :

Pairs may be : (2,2),(3,3) ....(K,K) etc.

$^{13}C_1 \times ^{13}C_1 \times ^{50}C_2$

But not getting the right answer.. please suggest..

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329318/probability-of-having-exactly-1-pair-from-drawing-5-cards  ?  and http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/probability/solved-examples-page8.aspx

Comment: Did you search Wikipedia on binomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your solution.

For one, ${}^{13}C_1$ gives the number of ways to choose a card denomination *without specifying a suit*, but we *have* to specify a suit and a denomination to specify a card. To choose two cards of the same denomination, then, we must choose a denomination *and* must choose $2$ of the $4$ possible suits.

Now, to pick $2$ cards that are *not* a pair, and do *not* have the same denomination as the pair we've chosen, we must pick $2$ of the remaining cards in the deck, to be sure. However, ${}^{50}C_2$ gives the number of ways to choose *any* $2$ of the remaining cards, which allows for $4$ of a kind, $3$ of a kind, and $2$ pairs. We don't want any of these things to happen! Instead, we should pick $2$ of the denominations we haven't already picked from (How many such denominations are there? How many ways can we pick two of them?) and then pick a suit for each denomination.

Can you put it all together?